# Unit tests assert vs Mockito.verify()

Tags: java, mockito

Fiddling around with Mockito for implementing unit tests of my services but for some reason I can't get this through my thick skull. My tests are passing but I am not conviced that I am doing it right.

Here is an example where I test the count() method. The method simply forwards the call to its repository and I wan't to verify that only that and nothing else happens. This is what I've got:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PersonServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonServiceImpl personService;

    @Test
    public void testCount() {

        when(personRepository.count()).thenReturn(2L);

        long count = personService.count();

        assertEquals(2L, count);

        verify(personRepository).count();
    }
}
```

My test is passing but I have some questions.

1. Is the assertEquals needed? as I understand it, whatever I put as the expected result of the method stub (.thenReturn(value..)) will ALWAYS be the value returned. Or could it be something else in this scenario?
2. Do I need the verify? I feel like I do because I want to verify that personRepository.count() was actually called. Or is that redundant when I have assertEquals() as well?
3. Do I need both assertEquals and verify?
4. And finally, am I doing this right :)

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it right.

You are injecting a mock repository into a real service, then testing the service. When it comes to business logic in your service, anything could be happening. That's why it's important to verify the code with known inputs and known outputs, just like you're doing.

1. You're checking the result of the business logic, given the response from the repository. This particular code is fairly straightforward, but imagine if the business logic was providing an average or a sum, not just the same value provided from the repository.
2. and 3. The verify and the assertEquals are testing different things. The verify checks that your repository method was called, the assert checks that the service responded with the correct value. Imagine that your service method had a hard-coded `return 2L`. The assertEquals would pass, but the verify would fail.
3. Yes, you're doing it right. What you're testing is linked to Why you're testing. Whether a particular assertion or verify is required is usually down to the individual situation. In this case, there is little point in testing that your repository method returns `2L`, but there is a good case for testing that your service returns `2L`. Similarly, there is no point in testing that the service method has been called, but there's a good case for testing that the repository method has been called.

You now have the tools to test your service, the next step is determining which tests to write.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful input that made me understand. All answers here were very helpful but this made me see it most clearly. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

In order:

1. **Is the `assertEquals()` needed:** It depends. Is there anything done to the result of `personRepository.count()` in `personService` before it is returned, that has any possibility of changing its value? If the answer is "definitely not", then you might not need to `assertEquals()` - but if there's any chance something might go wrong, then `assertEquals()` will make sure it didn't.
2. **Do you need `verify()`:** It depends. Is there any chance that `personRepository.count()` wasn't called? Or that it was called more than once (`verify()` by default expects its argument to be called exactly once)? If not, then you might not need it.
3. **Do you need both:** It depends (noticing a pattern?). See above: they do different things. There are many cases in which you want both things to be checked: 1. that the right result is returned, and 2. that the result is returned by doing the things you expect to be done.
4. **Are you doing this right:** Well... It depends. Does `personRepository.count()` look like

   ```
   public int count() {
       return this.personService.count();
   }
   ```

If so, you probably don't need much testing for it at all. If you insist on having a test, skipping `verify()` is probably alright, because the method above has **no other way of getting a value** than by calling the function you would be `verify`ing, and it returns that value, so it could hardly call it more than once.

On the other hand, if your function looks like:

```
public int count() {
    // get a personService from an injector
    // log the personService's details
    // generate a random number
    // try calling count() on personService, catch an error
    // if you caught the error, return the random number
}
```

Then maybe you **do** want to `verify()` because all of a sudden, there are a lot of things going on and some of them (i.e. the random number) could be confused for correct functioning even if something is going horribly wrong.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, also very informative. I think I might as well always include an assert and a verify then regardless of how simple the actual method is. An extra test never hurts right? Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Ehhhhh sure, but they **can** lead to a false sense of security (more tests != more confidence in your code), and they have an opportunity cost. Instead of writing redundant tests for this method, you could be writing valuable tests for some other, more complicated method. Keep in mind also: your tests are a form of documentation. People seeking to understand your functional code will read your test cases. Therefore, just like comments, tests should be clear, and they should not be redundant

Answer (score 1):

It is better to inject `PersonRepository` through a constructor rather than `@InjectMocks`. This also eliminates the need for a specific runner (or, later in your testing, involving Spring for low-level tests).

Your use of Mockito is *correct* but not optimal. You do need the `assertEquals` because what you're testing is that *the service* returns the same value as you are providing from the repository. The `verify...count` is not necessary because it's implied by checking that the appropriate value was returned. You can improve this by returning a random number instead of `2`.

Also check whether it's really worth wrapping `count()` in another object or if you're just adding unnecessary layers.

Finally, you might consider examining [Spock](http://spockframework.org); it's a Groovy-based test language on top of JUnit that provides a clean and powerful mock language.

Comment: One can argue about inject. It helps you to keep things clean; why add another ctor, when you only would need that for testing?

Comment: @GhostCat You shouldn't be adding "another" constructor, your injected constructor should be your only one. Field injection is a mess.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am actually using constructor injection of the repository to my service. Like GhostCat mentioned i prefer @InjectMock for the same reason. And also I do prefer wrapping all repo methods inside a service regardless of how simple they are. I intend to write a controller for this later on and I never want to call a repo from a controller. But perhaps this is not what you meant. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can get these things from your test:

- You are doing **Unit test** for Service layer (*)

  > ```
  > @InjectMocks
  > private PersonServiceImpl personService;
  > ```
- Your test methodology is **White-box** (**)

  > verify(personRepository).count();

(*) is because you are using real object for Service and mocking everything else (as @InjectMocks will try to instantiate your Service with mocked Repository as dependency)

(**) is because you care about *how the system works* (the call to Service.count() in-turn dispatches the call to Repository.count()).

Based on that assumption, here are answers to your questions (not in your order):

2.

> Do I need the verify?

It depends on what you care about:

- If you care about HOW a Service should work behind the scence aka doing White-box testing (eg: service must dispatch the call to Repository, not hard-code values), you DO need the verify to enforce the implementation design. In future, your test may fail and you will know that fail is as expectation or not (implementation design changed or bug fixing side effect, etc). More tests you should consider to add when taking this approach: Is log printed ? Is repository.count() called for exactly once ? etc. See [White-box_testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/)
- If you care about WHAT the result is when *service.count()* is called aka doing Black-box testing, you DO NOT need to verify the method call. Instead, there are more tests you should consider to add: IS service.count() 0 when repository.count() is 0 ? Does service.count() throw exception when repository.count() throws exception ? See [Black-box_testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing).

  Because we have to stub the *repository*'s count() to test *service*'s count(), people usually confused this approach with white-box testing but it's not since we care about the context WHEN service.count() returns that value, not how.
- Of course you can care about both WHAT the result is and HOW the result was calculated but it is not recommended since it will make your test complicated and hard to maintain.

3. 

> Do I need both assertEquals and verify?

Again, I assumpt that you are doing white-box testing.
Although you are doing white-box testing - verify is more important here, at least 1 sainity test is recommended. So you are doing correctly in this case.

1.

> Is the assertEquals needed?

As explained above, yes, *assertEquals* is needed.

> as I understand it, whatever I put as the expected result of the method stub (.thenReturn(value..)) will ALWAYS be the value returned.

1. You are stubbing a method of Repository class, which is a dependency - not your test target (Service)
2. You are asserting the result of your test target (Service)

So you are doing it correctly.

4.

> And finally, am I doing this right :)

This is a good typical white-box test I think :)

References:

- [White-box_testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/)
- [Black-box_testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing)